# Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop -- Video Driver Problems (again)

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, gpu-driver, scaling

I think there's a problem with my display drivers, but I'm not really sure.

I have a Lenovo Y50 laptop, with `integrated intel graphics (4th gen)` and an `Nvidia 860M` graphics card. I had 15.04 installed and I tried the nvidia drivers. It made such a mess of my system that I ended up wiping the HD and reinstalling ubuntu from scratch.

I upgraded to 15.10 -- great. I tried the nvidia drivers again. None of the nvidia drivers work, at all. I get the logon screen, when I enter my password it just resets back to the logon screen again. I've tried them all. I've even tried adding `nomodeset` to my grub configuration, and nada.

So, I switched to the terminal and did this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

When I rebooted I managed to get back into my desktop again, but the windows manager was totally messed up, so I started `ccsm` and reenabled unity to get them back. Beautiful.

But, the graphics are so slow, and the display scaling isn't working at all -- which is a huge problem because this laptop has a 4k display and now I can't read sh1t. And, I can't watch videos because the frame rate is about 1 frame a second.

I searched on t'internet, and found a way to reset things to factory settings:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
reboot
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
sudo apt-get autoremove
reboot
```

`reboot` is an alias for `shutdown -r now`

But, it fixed nothing. I've also tried this to fix the scaling problem:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

But all that does is mess up the terminal window and has no effect anywhere else.

My question is, how do I get back to the factory settings?

Here's some useful data that might help someone figure out what's wrong:

```
sudo lshw -c video

*-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d1000000-d13fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

And, `sudo lspci -mm | grep VGA` gives me this:

```
00:02.0 "VGA compatible controller" "Intel Corporation" "4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller" -r06 "Lenovo" "Device 3978"
```

The ever helpful `inxi -Gx`, returns:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.2 drivers: fbdev (unloaded: vesa) FAILED: intel
           Resolution: 3840x2160@88.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

And, finally, the end of my `Xorg.1.log`:

```
[    76.582] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
        i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
        915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
        Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
        GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    76.582] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    76.582] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    76.582] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    76.582] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    76.582] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    76.582] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    76.582] (++) using VT number 7

[    76.582] (II) intel(G0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20141121
[    76.582] (II) intel(G0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917-1~exp1ubuntu2.2 (Alessio Treglia <quadrispro@ubuntu.com>)
[    76.582] (II) intel(G0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    76.582] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    76.582] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    76.582] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    76.582] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    76.582] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    76.582] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    76.582]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.0.2
[    76.582]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    76.582] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    76.582] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    76.582] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    76.582] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[    76.582] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    76.582] (EE) no screens found(EE)
```

Forget gaming -- I promise not to try to use nvidia drivers ever again, if I can just get back to acceptable desktop performance and scaling (the scaling bit is key really, even slow is ok if I can at least read it).